# Placing HTML Pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

My css looks like this;

```
p:not(.dummy):after
{
    content: url(../../irhiddenchars/img/afterimage_9x9.gif);
}
```

I wish to take a taller (height) gif, but my lineheigth is increased when the css gets applied (even though there seems to be enough space for a bigger picture, line-height for a p-tag is 18px). Is it possible to place the pseudo element containing the gif somehow a little bit higher on the page?
Is there any other solution?

Comment: FYI: content selector not supported in IE7 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it dropping the image after approach (i had an image showing a Pilcrow symbol). Instead i use the Pilcrow character (which gets rendered according to the fontsize choosen):

```
body.hiddenchars p:after
{
    content: '\00b6';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `margin` and `padding` to `0`. The `p` elements (among others) have a implicit standard mark-up determined by the browser.

I'm still wondering however why you use the `:after` pseudo-class instead of nesting an `img`. Any specific reason for that?

**Edit:** Wow, this question is 2 months old, why did it appear on the recent questions page?

Comment: I am working with a rte editor and the aim is to show hidden characters and paragraphs. To place an img inside the editors content is not an option because of many other problems following this approach.

Answer (score -1):

use jQuery, not only to insert the content but you can then give it a class and style it to position exactly where you want it.

Comment: how would the jQuery code look like if i want to set the above image?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, jQuery is not the answer to life, universe and everything.